# Rails 3 helper method available in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading an app to Rails 3. We have an Application Controller like the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     helper_method :current_user

     def current_user
       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
     end
```

Because we define "helper_method", "current_user" is available to all the views. It's available to the controllers because they all inherit from class ApplicationController.

However, when we were on 2.3.8, access to "current_user" was available through a model, but now it's not. Is there a way to get this exposed to the models?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I could suggest moving `current_user` into a helper like `UserHelper`, then you can include it in your model with `include UserHelper`.

You'll also have to `include UserHelper` in your ApplicationController, but  `helper :user` will include that like normal into your views too.

Comment: This causes a `stack level too deep` error for me, when the Model file is accessed.  Possibly won't work with rails 3.2 (I've tried with 3.2.3 and 3.2.8).

Comment: same here… any way to do it ?

Comment: sounds like you're doing some recursive calls that are getting it stuck in an endless cycle.